# Adjusting brightness and contrast before using Affectiva Emtion SDK?

Tags: affdex-sdk

Does the brightness or contrast of the video matter, i.e. should it be adjusted before using the Affectiva Emotion SDK so that the face is best visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, moderate levels of brightness and contrast are best. The SDK provides some feedback on brightness in the Face::faceQuality metric:

http://affectiva.github.io/developerportal/pages/platforms/v3_4_1/windows/classdocs/affdex-native/structaffdex_1_1_face_quality.html 1